# javascript client-side-only loading notification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorting a table (client-side) using jQuery. The table is variable length, and when the dataset is large, the sort can take around 3-5 seconds. I would like to show a div (id="sorting") with a spinner or "Please Wait" notification while javascript sorts my table. However, the notification isn't working as expected. Here is the gist of my code:

```
var sortableList;
var sortField;
var sortDir;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').delegate('.sortable-heading','click',function(){
        sortData($(this));
    });
});

function sortData(obj){
    $('#sorting').show();
    sortableList = [];
    $('.data-row').each(function(){
        var rowData = {};
        var sortKey = obj.attr('id');
        var i = obj.index();
        var val = $(this).find('td:eq(' + i + ') .val-text').text();
        if(sortKey == 'adjHeading'){
            val = $.trim(val);
        }else{
            val = $.trim(val) ? parseInt(val) : 0;
        }
        rowData[sortKey] = val;
        rowData.rowHtml = $(this).clone().wrap('<p />').parent().html();
        sortableList.push(rowData);
    });
    redrawTable(obj);
}

function redrawTable(obj){
    if(obj.attr('id') == sortField){
        sortDir = sortDir == true ? false : true;
    }
    sortField = obj.attr('id');
    var primer = sortField == 'adjHeading' ? function(a){return a.toUpperCase()} : parseInt;
    sortableList.sort(sort_by(sortField,sortDir,primer));

    $('#pivot-table-1').html(topRowHeading1 + topRowHeading2);
    for(var i in sortableList){
        $('#pivot-table-1').append(sortableList[i].rowHtml);
    }
    $('#sorting').hide();
}
```

When the click function fires, the table gets sorted, and I never see my loading div. If I comment out the $('#sorting').hide() call, the div gets displayed only AFTER the table gets sorted. I though javascript was supposed to execute from top-to-bottom. Any idea why it is not in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see something obviously wrong there, what happens if you return after $('#sorting').show(); so `$('#sorting').show();return;` The table should not be sorted but the loading should show (I think something goes wrong there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser page will act like a single threaded application where at a time there will be only one task running like running a script/updating the UI/reacting to user events etc

In your case soon after calling `show()` the next scripts are running which takes some time thus the browser does not get any time to update the UI to show the element. The solution here is to use a `setTimeout` after showing the element so that the browser will get freed to show the element and then execute the next scripts

```
function sortData(obj){
    $('#sorting').show();

    setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
        sortableList = [];
        $('.data-row').each(function(){
            var rowData = {};
            var sortKey = obj.attr('id');
            var i = obj.index();
            var val = $(this).find('td:eq(' + i + ') .val-text').text();
            if(sortKey == 'adjHeading'){
                val = $.trim(val);
            }else{
                val = $.trim(val) ? parseInt(val) : 0;
            }
            rowData[sortKey] = val;
            rowData.rowHtml = $(this).clone().wrap('<p />').parent().html();
            sortableList.push(rowData);
        });
        redrawTable(obj);
    }, this))

}
```

Comment: It's worth explaining why this would work.  In the original code the div is not shown because the javascript is busy performing the sort.  In this answer you are showing the div, using setTimeout to yield to the rendering thread so that the div is displayed, and only *then* are you starting the sort

Comment: Nice. This works, I did need to add a small time interval as 2nd argument to the setTimeout function though to make it work. But yes this is a nice solution, thanks.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex that was the plan.. but got into something else soon after posting the answer...